# Collatz conjecture: What if we prove $3x+1$ cycles factors?

Tags: factoring, collatz-conjecture, permutation-cycles

I'm not a mathematician but this problem interested me so I thought about it for a bit. My current understanding is that it needs proof that there is NOT a number that fails to pass the conjecture, but what if we simply prove that $3x+1$ DOES cycle all factors?

$4,2,1$ in factors is just just ($2 \cdot 2$), ($2$), ($1$). Since $1$ is an odd number, apply $3x+1$ which means $3(1)+1=4$, or ($2\cdot 2$), and it loops. For any odd number, $x$, the expression $3x+1$ always results in creating $2$ as a factor, which we then remove by $n/2$. The end result is the original number has had its factors shuffled.

For example, if $x=9$, then

$$3(9)+1 = 3(3 \cdot 3)+1 = 28 = (7 \cdot 2 \cdot 2)$$

So we then eliminate the $2$s and result in a transformation of the factors from ($3\cdot 3$) to just ($7$).

I would hypothesize that shuffling like this eventually will always result in a permutation that contains only $2$ to some power as factors. If in theory we can prove that $3x+1$ cycles through all prime numbers, doesn't that prove that eventually you will invariably end up with a number that contains only factors of $2$? Or is that proof not good enough? Also I don't know how to prove that, obviously. I just had this idea, tried looking it up and found nothing so I wasn't sure if people hadn't thought about it or if there is a good reason why this isn't considered.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: That is in fact the conjecture, that a number will somehow always reduce to one with ONLY factors of two. It is easily provable that a number will always shuffle to one with SOME factors of two, but there's no telling where the rest of it will go from there

Comment: The difficulty to prove this conjecture (I am not aware of serious trials for a disproof) is the dynamic. Adding $1$ changes the prime factors completely and it is in no way obvious that a power of $2$ will eventually be hit. In fact, similar sequences lead to nontrivial cycles and a generalized version of Collatz has shown to be even undecidable.

Comment: General comment : In the case of such famous conjectures , we can safely assume that the "obvious/easy" approaches have been already tried. Surely, we cannnot enumerate every relatively easy idea but the easier an idea is the more likely is that someone would have found it.  Some people even claim that it is impossible that an "easy" idea was overlooked, but I think this is an exaggerating statement.

Comment: Note that a prime factor can appear multiple times in the same Collatz trajectore.
The trajectory of $45$ goes to $1$ through $5$, for example.